# Wget: Downloading Specific HTML Files

Tags: wget

I have been searching unsuccessfully for an answer but have drawn a blank so far. Does Wget have the capability to download specific html files using a "keyword" from the text in the Title tag of the html file? I thought perhaps "--follow-tag" might do it but the Title tag is not included in the Wget tag database. Yes, I know I could filter out the files after download but didn't want to use that option. 
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
wget -q `grep -oP '(?<=<url>).*?(?=</url>)' test.html`
```

It would search for any url inside `<url></url>` tags from inside `test.html` file and download it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly so a simple analogy would be as follows bearing in mind that I don't know the URLs or the html file names of the downloads I am seeking. Say the site has 100 linked URLs. Within the <Title></Title> tags 90 of them have the following information = "Current Production + Marques + Manufacturer" the other 10 have the information = "Vintage + Marques + Manufacturer". If Wget could somehow use the keyword "Vintage" from the Title tag as a filter only those 10 would be downloaded  with the 90 excluded.

Comment: When you said "the site has 100", did you know the URL of the site or not? You're still not explaining clearly. List down what do you know, and what do you expect of the result. Give examples...

Comment: Yes I would know the name of the site. The linked URLs in it would be serially numbered www.....001.htm, 002.htm, 003.htm etc up to ...100.htm. The URL itself gives no indication as to what the file contains as that info is only found consistently within the markup <title> tag (apart from studiously examining the contents of each file). If vintage files had been placed in a "vintage" folder Xenu could have been used to identify that but no use here. The outcome looked for is just the naming of the 10 relevant files about vintage marques which could be say, 003.htm, 304.htm, 040.htm etc